# MAJOR: Unused private method should be removed - postConstruct Annotation - false positive

Tags: sonarqube

We use the `@PostConstruct` Annotation for setup Methods (Spring Dependency Injection (`@Autowired`)) and get a false positive:

> "Unused private method should be removed"

```
@PostConstruct
private void setupAbc() {
...
}
```

any hints?

Comment: the same is true for methods annotated with @Autowired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule will skip annotated private unused methods, it will be fixed in version sonar-java-plugin version 3.6.
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1179